# IBM BigInsights main class not found error

Tags: biginsights

I have tried deploying my BigInsight natured Java program directly from Eclipse. But it is showing a "class not found" error.

But when I added the runnable jar of the same project in run time dependencies while deploying the Application, it worked fine.

At the time of BigInsight application publish, it must add all of the dependencies of the particular projects. Is there any option in the UI that lets me do the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a BigInsights application created inside of a BigInsights natured Eclipse project then the directory structure will look like this prior to application publish:

- Project

  - src
  - BIApp

    - application
    - workflow

      - lib
      - workflow.xml
  - textAnalytics

Only the jars placed into the workflow/lib folder prior to application publish will be packaged automatically and made available during runtime.  This includes any code that exists in the src directory, which must also be jarred manually and placed into the lib directory if it is to be made available at runtime.  It is suggested to have all of your application code as well as your dependencies inside of workflow/lib as jars prior to publish.  If all code and dependencies have not yet been placed into workflow/lib prior to publish they may still be added on the final page of the application publish wizard; the page titled "Zip and Publish Application".